# How to add an interface to a window

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, interface

Apologies for this question which shows that I am new to C#.

I have a project that defines an interface:

```
public interface IExampleType
{
    void DisplayMessage();
}
```

now I want to add a WPF project that uses that interface.
Should it be a Console project I'd do:

```
public class ExampleType : MarshalByRefObject, IExampleType
{
    public void DisplayMessage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Message1");
    }
}
```

but I want to have full WPF capabilities so my project has:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void DisplayMessage()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Message1");
    }
}
```

now I have problems in add the interface since I can't do

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, MarshalByRefObject, IExampleType
```

for that would be multiple inherithance.
Nor

```
public partial class MainWindow : MarshalByRefObject, IExampleType
```

since I get the error:

> Error CS0263  Partial declarations of 'MainWindow' must not specify different base classes

So how can I have a project that inherits from Window and abides by an interface?

thanx

Comment: Why is the `MainWindow` inheriting from `MarshalByRefObject`?

Comment: The problem is not the interface but MarshalByRefObject which is a class, you can do multiple inheritances while there is only one class and multiple interfaces.

Comment: Thank you that solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not the interface it's the fact that you can't have multiple inheritance of classes.  So you can not have MainWindow inherit MarshalByRefObject and Window.  The moral of the story is that you can only inherits one class (in the case of MainWindow this is Window or a class that inherits window) and any number of Interfaces